# Netstat -ano. What does this mean..?

Tags: networking, netstat

Getting an output that shows a specific process or group of processes (listed as PIDs) in `netstat -ano`.

The PIDs seem to be connecting to multiple 'Foreign Address' IPs, or perhaps trying to spam multiple foreign IPs. That's **IF** I'm interpreting the output correctly.

Here's an example of the outputs in question. Does the  `:` output mean '`wildcard IP : wildcard port`' ?

Therefore meaning those PIDs are trying to, or literally broadcasting on all IPs?

If so, how to stop them doing so?

Your assistance much appreciated.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
PROTO  Local Address   Foreign Address PID
UDP    0.0.0.0:12345   *:*             2384
```

Comment: it means "all IPs; all ports". UDP, unlike TCP, has no Listening ports, because its not connection-orriented. as a result a service that has a udp port open will accept traffic on it (in this case from any IP on any port).

Comment: So the processes in question are trying to contact every Foreign Address they possibly can? There's no way I'd want that functionality on a home desktop.

Comment: no, process 2348 is accepting traffic from anyone who sends it to them. netstat is telling you that there is a port, opened by 2384, that will accept traffic on all its nics on port 12345, and will take that traffic from any IP using any port. it is not telling you about a connection, just an opened port. UDP doesn't have connections.